# Should vague titles be edited to be more descriptive?

Tags: discussion

It seems like we have gotten a few vague titles lately:

- [What is the best database design for this situation?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17650/what-is-the-best-database-design-for-this-situation)
- [SQL Server memory usage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17647/sql-memory-usage)
- [Select rows where value of second column is not present in first column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16650/help-with-this-select-in-the-same-table) (maybe)

If the community member feels a title is vague, should it be edited to be more specific?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Definitely.

The title is the most visible part of a question.  Having a clear title is very important for both SEO and for clarity and functionality.

As long as you are not changing the content/spirit of the title, and not adding meta information (like adding tags to the body of the  title) then I think this should be encouraged.

Comment: On the other hand, making a title too long and descriptive is annoying too. Sometimes the question title does not need to describe the entire context of the question, even though sometimes they are edited to do just that. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good point.

Comment: Not only that, but this is how we have a community oriented site :D Get involved!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they should, as should poorly worded but cogent questions.  There are quite a lot of questions posed by inarticulate OPs (first langauge C) that are poorly worded and difficult to understand but are actually sensible questions.  Editing the questions and titles to clarify is entirely sensible as it makes the question more useful to other readers as well.